What to do with gap discovered between bath and wall when recaulking
We've been recaulking my bathroom since the original caulk was coming off and aren't 100% sure what to do next.
It was put there by the previous owner. It was really hard to remove, and I think it was expanding foam.
Attached is a photo of the side of the tub not fully cleaned up yet. In the top corner there's a two inch gap that's too wide to caulk. I also noticed there's no back to caulk against, just the side of the wall and side of bath with space between behind right into the dry wall. If I understand correctly there should also be a back in addition to the sides? I looked at a backer rod but that also confused me as doesn't that need a back to go up against too?
If somebody could please help clarify what we should do here that would be great. I've thought about filling in the corner with hydraulic cement so there's a narrow enough caulk line, using expanding foam etc, but I'm not sure. Thanks! [

This looks like the installer didn't have the tools to better follow the tub profile. The probabilty that you have matching tile is low. If you are lucky enough that you do not have the same problem at the other end of the tub, I would take the lower piece out and replace it with a piece of tile closely matching the color of the tub and thickness of the existing tile and cut it so that it matches the profile. That being said, anything you do will be obvious.

Thanks. I took a other photo and I don't know if you can see well, but there is no wall behind the bath. It's empty space until it reaches the inside or the drywall in my hallway. I have no idea how to install a bath or tiles, just recaulk - could you please confirm if it's normal for a space to be there like that?

Hm after further reading if I'm correct, a bathtub should have a lip at a right angle to the side of the tub (a flange?) which would then be attached to the wall. In this case the tub ends without that and there's no wall/panel at the end of the tub.

The lip exists around the top of the tub on three sides. Technically, your issue is with the tub skirt, not the tub itself.

Any chance you can find matching tiles?
